# Should I mark every glossary term, or only the first one?

Tags: thesis, glossary

There are some terms in my Bachelor's thesis which I would rather add to a glossary list. Say that the term appears on page 23, 25 and 31. Should I only mark the first occurrence, or should I mark them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pattern that I have repeatedly seen and that seems reasonable is:

- mark all occurrences (maybe excluding mere mentions of something that is not discussed or applicable at that location)
- bold the page number of the "main" occurrence (e.g. definition, detailed description, etc., not necessarily the first one)

Comment: I have looked at many thesises but most of them randomly marked some terms and some terms not, and some thesises did not mark their terms at all... I guess my university's requirements are not that high. Thanks!